# Connecting headphones to mcu

Tags: microcontroller, power-supply, resistors, analog, speakers

We need to connect a small speaker- a headphone one, to an Microchip Pic.
I don't know whats the resistance of such speaker(it's very small) but I guess it's 8-ohm. (We are only using one headphone speaker, not both.)

I know the Pic can output 20mA in a port, so with `5V` output and `20mA` I have about `0.1W` to use, which is good enough (Does not have to be audible to humans, this will be audio-coupled to a microphone).

Not knowing the speaker's impedance or current requirements, I was wondering if connecting them with a 300Ω resistor, directly to the mcu (with a dc blocking component), would produce something, or am I missing something?

**Please** don't advice an op-amp. I know about them, but am trying to avoid that, because I need a small signal and very small power draw.

Comment: Headphones are often 16-32 ohms. Also, "class D amplifier".

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams class D is overkill for a headphone speaker. Overkill might be a understatement.

Comment: @Passerby: Sure, but if he's connecting it to a MCU anyways then he gets one for free.

Comment: 300 ohm and a series decoupling capacitor would work ok if you are just feeding tones - don't expect audio unless you are PWM modulating the logic signal from the MCU.

Comment: The 300R seems like a bad idea, most of your tiny output power will end up there and not in the headphone?

Comment: @pjc50: You need a low-pass filter for any sort of sound that isn't supposed to be an ear-piercing squeal.

Comment: i will output a pwm tones, that can be very low, so only a close microphone can hear.. for this i need to find the right setup

Comment: so actually its a very interesting question, from one side you have a nice 0.1w potential , from the other side you have to put a big resistor to limit the current, but big resistor will take all the power for him, so what do you do in that situation ?

Comment: @Curnelious DC power and resistance do not translate equally to AC power and impedance. Remember, speakers are AC components, while resistors are DC.

Comment: you right . so whats the exact math ?

Comment: There are small amplifier/driver IC's out there, Fairchild FAB1200 came up from a very quick google.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While this is a less authoritative answer than I prefer to give, frankly, yes, that should work.

There are many projects where a speaker is directly connected to a microcontroller through just a resistor. The [Arduino Tone library and Tutorial](http://arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/tone) is one such example. The Arduino uses an Atmel ATMega328 (or similar), with a similar current limit (40mA, with voltage droop). The example/recommended setup is an 8Ω speaker connected with an 100Ω resistor. While speaker Impedance is not the same type of Ohms as DC Resistance, the combination of greater impedance of your headphone speaker (Typically 16-32Ω) and higher limiting resistor (300Ω as you mentioned) should be enough to both produce sound and protect the Pic's output pin.

Most often, a DC blocking capacitor is not needed in these limited situations.

Then again, this is my educated guess.

The other option is using a single npn transistor for the speaker. This might be sufficient if a direct connection is not.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help ! but with 300 ohm resistor, and a 16 ohm speaker, the resistor takes all the power for himself, isnt it ? and about the transistor, because some restriction ,we didnt wanted to put one, but if you have some circuit diagram that uses only 1 transistor,not too many things around him, i will be happy to hear. thanks again.]

Comment: @Curnelious: Connecting the speaker and filter across complementary outputs will increase the output power.

Comment: i dont get you. you say i should output the signal from 3 ports of the mcu, to the speaker ?

Comment: Use 2 outputs. When one outputs a high the other outputs a low, and vice versa.

Comment: @Curnelious it shouldn't. And you could adjust the resistor as needed (a trim pot can be used for testing).